# Pass action to controller custom controller method - ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameter-passing, action

How can I pass the action a user is taking to a method within my controller?

For example:

```
before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

If the user tries to use the :edit action before logging in in my method I would like to say something like this:

```
def require_login 
  unless current_user
    if (:edit action)
      flash[:alert] = "You must log in before you are able to edit foo"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `params[:action]` what you're after?

```
flash[:alert] = "You must log in before you are able to #{params[:action]} foo"
```

`params[:controller]` should be available too